# A visual interpretation of probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

I was using the following website for a visual information theory : http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-09-Visual-Information/.

And I came across the following:
[image: Picture]

So it says that in the first image where the lines are straight the events are independent.  But in the second picture when the events are not independent then the lines are bloated. I am wondering why the reason is so. It says here that some of the areas are bloated and some are not, and this is how we know that one event is more probable than the other. But how does that factor into independence? Even in the first picture, one portion of the area is bigger than the other. So how does the area matter or give us an answer about independence?

Comment: Do you know what the definition of independence is?

Answer (score 1):

Conditional probability works in a reduced sample space.
$$ \begin{array}{r}  \begin{array}{c|c|c}
  \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{clothing today}\bigg\\ \text{weather today}}  & \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Raining}}  & \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Sunny}}  \\\hline
  \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{T-shirt}}  & a  & b & 62\%
\\\hline
  \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Coat}}  & c  & d & 38\%
  \\\hline&25\%&75\%&100\%\end{array} 
 \end{array}\hskip-5.5pt$$
Coat and Raining are $\color{red}{\textbf{independent}}$ events iff $$\frac{c}{a+c}=\frac{P(\text{Coat}\cap \text{Raining})}{P(\text{Raining})}=P(\text{Coat}|\text{Raining})\color{red}{\textbf{ = }} P(\text{Coat})=\frac{c\quad+\quad d}{a+c\quad+\quad b+d}.$$ This means that Coat and Raining are **independent** events iff the Coat area (whether we choose box $c$ or $d$ or $c+d$) is proportional to its corresponding column area.

This is equivalent to the given illustration having dividing lines that are each either vertical straight or horizontal straight.

Answer (score 0):

While I think that that visual is not particularly helpful, in no small part because the exterior is nonsensical, there is a way to interpret it reasonably. In the first case, you can pick any information from the clothing axis, and gain no more information about the weather. Similarly, you can pick any information from the weather axis and gain no more information about the clothing. This is to say that if we compare the whole graph to a subset obtained by focusing on part of one axis, the graph is largely unchanged.

On the other hand, this process fails in the second diagram. If I restrict to "coat" section, the graph is telling me that it is more likely to be raining - I have gained more knowledge about the weather variable by being more specific in my investigation of the clothing variable.

This is the crux of independence and dependence. Two variables are independent if adding information about one does not give you new information about the other.

Comment: That raises the question of what a better way would be to visualize the information introduced by dependence.

Comment: I guess it depends on the individual. Two examples that come to mind for me are bivariate Gaussians and possibly something to do with a filtration by time. More elementary examples in the style of the above could be done just by being more careful in sketching.

Comment: @Semiclassical I think they could have just had the unit box as in the upper sketch (no wavy boundary) and randomly sketched out four regions in the bottom box with the 4 colors used above to indicate the 4 outcomes of this experiment (and make sure that the volumes were different than what is given since for 2 Bernoulli RVs, those 4 volumes automatically imply independence). (So maybe just drag the second half of the upper line below to enlarge the upper right corner)